# If statement using string function

Tags: python, string, if-statement

For a learning project, I try to write a program that asks for a name, and then display "Access granted" if and only if the name is "Thomas".

So far, I wrote this.

```
name = str(input("What is your name?"))

if name == "Thomas":
print("Access granted")
```

I would expect it to work as described earlier, but instead I get this error message :

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What does this message mean and how to fix it ? I don't know where to start.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't help anyone to help you. The snippet you have isn't valid Python (`if` should be lower-case, `print()` should be indented) and `Name` and `name` are different identifiers.

Comment: It doesn't work because `Name` is not the same as `name` (case-sensitivity), `If` doesn't exist in the language, it would be `if` and you didn't indent it correctly

Comment: Hey, I edited your question to format it in a way that makes it easier to understand what you are trying to achieve and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python the indentation counts, and is a part of the syntax !

So you should correct your code this way :

```
name = str(input("What is your name?"))

if name == "Thomas":
    print("Access granted")
```